# Using same code for multiple apps on same google play dev account

Tags: android, google-play

So, I have created a weather app for my city using ionic framework (my own code not reskined). And, I'm using the code base for that weather app for different cities in my country. Each time, I'm just changing the variables storing the name and coordinates of the cities, putting a new adsence app id and banner id, and publishing it as a new app each time.

Is this something considered to be against the Google Play Terms of Service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding Google Play support should be asked on the relevant support forums.

Comment: Thanks for your input, can you please direct me where I can ask this ? So I can remove this from here.

Comment: Beware the [Google Play Developer RPC](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/#!?zippy_activeEl=repetitive-content#repetitive-content)...

Comment: The ToS specifically say not do to what you want to do. They're going to say there's zero reason why this has to be multiple apps, and they're right. Have it be one app, and let the user select the city.